# Decode a special chanracter

Tags: html, html-entities

Hi I want to decode this special character **±**. The problem is, the name contains the special character and when I try to write it in html it is been encoded and shown as &#177; So please help me to decode this special characters.

Comment: Decode from what and into what?

Comment: I want to write that **±** symbol on form. But it is showing as &amp;#177; The example word which I'm trying to write in form is    DVD±RW

Comment: It seems like you are suffering from a double-encoding of HTML entities. You should update your questions with more details on what platform you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
      &plusmn;
```

**Refrence:**

http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/latin1.html

Comment: I don't think this will help, because there seems to be one escaping too much, it will be changed to something like `&amp;plusmn;`.

Comment: see here http://jsfiddle.net/srinivasan/DGJMZ/ your code  http://jsfiddle.net/srinivasan/DGJMZ/1/

Comment: Probably you missunderstood me, your example is correct, but S.Siva must have code somewhere, that is escaping the string two times.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the string variable always contains the `±` character, not an encoded string like `&#177;`. When you give it out to an UTF-8 encoded HTML page, the browser will show it correctly as `±`, even when using an escaping function like PHP's `htmlspecialchars()`.